# 500 HTTP Error When Deploying to DigitalOcean App Platform via Doctl

Tags: node.js, github, digital-ocean, github-actions

I've created a YAML spec for my DO App Platform based on the sample on this [repository](https://github.com/digitalocean/sample-monorepo).
The reason I couldn't simply use the UI on the DigitalOcean website is that my project is a monorepo.

Which looks like this:

```
name: unique-expressions

services:
  - name: api
    environment_slug: node-js
    github:
      repo: Valencian-Digital/unique-expressions
      branch: main
      deploy_on_push: true
    source_dir: api
    routes:
      - path: /api
```

But when I try to execute
`doctl apps create --spec .do/app.yaml`
It returns a 500 Error and nothing else. I've tried executing the command both in a Github action and locally with different API tokens.

I'm able to access other resources on my DO account but I can't successfully create the spec.

This is the specific error I get back from doctl:

```
Error: POST https://api.digitalocean.com/v2/apps: 500 Server Error
```

Do y'all what could be going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

So I discovered what was going wrong. Essentially the branch name was wrong (I put main instead of master).

You can find more info here: https://github.com/digitalocean/doctl/issues/883.

TLDR - this is the right config:

```
name: unique-expressions

services:
  - name: api
    environment_slug: node-js
    github:
      repo: Valencian-Digital/unique-expressions
      branch: master
      deploy_on_push: true
    source_dir: api
    routes:
      - path: /api
```